# Why MACsec can not reach more than 2Gbits/s?

Tags: linux, networking, performance, kernel, macsec

i am configuring macsec and i have discovered that, when using this protocol to send/received data, the bitrate is so low.

I am using it over a 10Gb network adaptor, using iperf3 it almost reach that value but when using MACsec over that interface, the highest value it has reach is 1,78Gbits/s.

I use "top" to check if there is something that is causing the cpu to spend time in other process, and i have seen that ksoftirqd uses almost 100% of the CPU.

How can i configure macsec to reach higher speed?

My network card is BCM57416 NetXtreme-E Dual-Media with RDMA Ethernet Controller and my kernel version is 5.15.0-76-generic

Answer (score 4):

Your MACsec encryption is most likely using the software implementation in the linux kernel.

I cannot find any information that your NIC support MACsec hardware offloading.

So your options are:

- Upgrade to a better CPU (most likely only give a small increase in throughput)
- Use a NIC that supports hardware offloading

Comment: -1


But I have an Intel Xeon Gold 6426Y as CPU, maybe some configuration or service make macsec slower? As i said before, if i use iperf3 on that interface i get 9,89 Gbits/s but when i configure macsec on that interface and transmit data throught that, i got 1.6 Gbits/s. Maybe the load of the CPU is not as much relevant as i thought